# Checking if avro schema is according to the avro spec

Tags: avro

I cannot find a tool for checking whether avro schemas follow the avro spec.  How can I check this?

I have generated a 300kB avro schema, but I do not know whether its syntax is according to the avro spec.  The avro spec has quite a few quirks, like naming conventions, handling records in records and other quirks.

What is more, if I try my avro schema using a tool that validates json according to an avro schema, I get an unspecified error or crash.

Is there a tool, maybe a JSON Schema validator that can validate the avro schema itself?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to validate the schema definition, then it's enough to try to build an object that is generated by the schema definition. You can do it in a unit test for example and when you will run the unit test, an exception will be thrown if you will not respect the avro schema definition.

If you want to check for compatibility issues, then you can use the Schema Registry REST API, more details [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html).

Best regards!

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue unless there is a tool that will create an object based on the schema.

Comment: I don't understand very well you statement. From your question seems that you are looking for a way to validate your avro schema definition.

Comment: Yes.  But if I have to make a document, that job in itself might be bigger than generating the schema definition.